# How to make Visual Health Meter follow the Player using Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

**Problem I am having is locating the method to combine Player Position and adding to it** I am trying to figure this out to help explain to my kid who is learning pygame and keeps coming up with questions beyond my scope of knowledge.

[image: health] [image: healthbar] [image: player] [image: Better example]

**My goal:** is to have a **Visual Life Meter** that is following or stuck to the Player/Enemy floating above it in order to keep track of collision detections in a more visual manner.

**I am getting stuck with the concept of how to combine PlayerPos of the player img with the sprite meter**

**My Problem Area is understanding what to do for the healthbarpos to glue it the current player position**

**playerpos + player x position ,player y position + 10 pixels**

```
    #How I keep the player position
playerpos=[50,50]


#How I keep health bar above the player position
healthbarpos=[


#the player image
PLAYER = pygame.image.load('player.png')
#the position of the player [x,y]
playerPos = [0,0]
```

As I move the player around the board it adds to the player position

```
   #if a key is pressed
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        #if the right arrow is pressed
        if event.key == K_RIGHT and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH - 1:
            #change the player's x position
            playerPos[0] += 1
        if event.key == K_LEFT and playerPos[0] > 0:
            #change the player's x position
            playerPos[0] -= 1
        if event.key == K_UP and playerPos[1] > 0:
            #change the player's x position
            playerPos[1] -= 1
        if event.key == K_DOWN and playerPos[1] < MAPHEIGHT -1:
            #change the player's x position
            playerPos[1] += 1
```

My novice assumptions are I need to store player current x Location plus 0 because it starts in same x location and also the players current y location + 10 pixels

I understand

```
 pygame.draw.rect(window, color, (x,y,width,height), thickness)
```

so I assume

```
pygame.draw.rect(window, color, (player x position ,player y position + 10 pixels,width,height), thickness)
```

## I believe understand the below life meter part in theory enough to do

```
#Initialize the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

#How I keep the player position
playerpos=[50,50]


#How I keep health bar above the player position
healthbarpos=[

playerpos + player x position ,player y position + 10 pixels


-----------------

#full bar 34 pixel minus 3 on each side so 28
healthvalue=28

#loading images for healthbar
healthbar = pygame.image.load("healthbar.png")
health = pygame.image.load("health.png")

#rest inside the while true loop

#Drawing health bar
    screen.blit(healthbar, (5,5))
    for health1 in range(healthvalue):
        screen.blit(health, (health1+8,8))
    #update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()

#Moving player in the event loop 

       #if a key is pressed
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #if the right arrow is pressed
            if event.key == K_RIGHT and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH - 1:
                #change the player's x position
                playerPos[0] += 1
            if event.key == K_LEFT and playerPos[0] > 0:
                #change the player's x position
                playerPos[0] -= 1
            if event.key == K_UP and playerPos[1] > 0:
                #change the player's x position
                playerPos[1] -= 1
            if event.key == K_DOWN and playerPos[1] < MAPHEIGHT -1:
                #change the player's x position
                playerPos[1] += 1
```

Comment: 2 comments, you have some uncomplete code `healthbarpos=[` and if you could give links to the two images, people could use them to try your setup.

Comment: yeah the healthbar pos is the part i had no clue what to put there. That is the exact part I have been stuck on. I added a few images I don't have my kids images but I made something similar quick to add. I actual which I knew more to phrase the question better.

Comment: Did you try what you actually said, and run into some problem? At first glance it looks like you have the right idea. You just want to add the same offset to the healthbar sprite every time the player moves before the re-draw - which is what you said.

Comment: I did try attempting several things in my mind for a few days now but I keep getting stuck on how to combine looking the current playerpos + player x position ,player y position and added  the healthbar to render 10 pixels above it. but in the end I did not actually get any further if that makes any sense.

Comment: this is a few of the many things I attempted healthbarpos=[playerposx, playerposy +10]   or should it be something healthbarpos . = [player.posx,  player.posy +10] but even as I type them they feel wrong just dont know why. I also thought maybe i create and 3rd obj and put them both the player and the meter inside it. I just dont want to confuse anyone as much as I did myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to not use separate coordinates for the health bar and player. Having two sets of coordinates is unnecessarily complicated.

When you draw the player and health bar, use coordinates derived from the player, and apply an offset.

```
screen.blit(healthbar, (playerPos[0], playerPos[1] - heightOfHealthBar))
```

or something like that in the draw function.

Comment: Great advice about not having the duplicate sets coords, I missed the on the golden rule of keep it simple stu...I will give this a try tonight it seams easier for me to wrap my mind around this method. I also probably should of created a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.